# Getting JavaScript variable in embeded C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to write a simple *for* in JS which uses an element from a list declared in C# code behind. Actually there is a problem here: `['i']` - compiler doesn't know what is `i`.

How can I write this for properly?

```
for (var i = 0; i < '<%= poz.Count %>'; i++) {
    var Latitude = '<%= poz['i'].Latitude %>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your counter variable is not defined in your c# code. It is a javascript variable.

If you want the values of your poz object to be available to javascript you need to write them out to some javascript structure with a loop written in c#.

Answer (score 2):

You have got this upside down. The C# must put all data in the HTML page for the JavaScript to get. Unless you provide an API, there is no way for the JS to get the data.

I suggest the following C# pseudocode that produces JavaScript in the HTML (note this is not perfect C#).

```
function myJsFunction()
{
    var jsLattitudes = {};
    <%
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < lattitudes.Length)
    {
        document.WriteLn(string.Format("jsLattitudes[{0}] = '{1}';\r\n", i, lattitues[i].Lattitude));
    }
    %>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var locations = [ { <%= string.Join("},\n{",
                        locations.Select(l => string.Format("Longitude: {0}, Latitude: {1}",
                        l.Longitude.ToString(),
                        l.Latitude.ToString()))) %> } ]

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var Longitude = locations[i].Longitude;
    var Latitude = locations[i].Latitude;
}
```

This assumes that you have a class like

```
public class Location
{
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

and locations is IEnumerable may be like this

```
var locations = new List<Location> {
    new Location { Longitude = 10, Latitude = 20 },
    new Location { Longitude = 11, Latitude = 21 },
    new Location { Longitude = 12, Latitude = 22 }
};
```